# Use of keys: Consolidating multiple <ul> with intervening <p> elements

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have multiple instances of xml similar to the following:

```
<refbody>
<ul>
    <li><uicontrol>FOO</uicontrol>BAR</li>
</ul>
<p>Values: 000 - 999</p>
<ul>
    <li><uicontrol>FOO</uicontrol>BAR</li>
    <li><uicontrol>FOO</uicontrol>BAR</li>
    <li><uicontrol>FOO</uicontrol>BAR</li>
    <li><uicontrol>FOO</uicontrol>BAR</li>
</ul>
<p>Values:</p>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
<p>lorem ipsum</p>
</refbody>
```

What I would like to have happen is to consolidate all `<ul>` elements into a single `<dl>`.

Each `<li>` should create a child `<dlentry>`.

Each `<uicontrol>` should become a `<dt>` that is a child of its `<dlentry>`.

The remaining text in the `<li>` should be put in a `<dd>` element, which is also a child of the `<dlentry>`.

My style sheet (provided below) accomplishes much this already. Where I am running into trouble is the last requirement:

Any `<p>` needs to be put inside of the `<dlentry>` associated with its `preceding-sibling::li[1]`.

So the desired result looks like this:

```
<refbody>
<dl>
    <dlentry>
        <dt>FOO</dt>
        <dd>BAR
            <p>Values: 000 - 999</p>
        </dd>
    </dlentry>
    <dlentry>
        <dt>FOO</dt>
        <dd>BAR</dd>
    </dlentry>
    <dlentry>
        <dt>FOO</dt>
        <dd>BAR</dd>
    </dlentry>
    <dlentry>
        <dt>FOO</dt>
        <dd>BAR</dd>
    </dlentry>
    <dlentry>
        <dt>FOO</dt>
        <dd>BAR
            <p>Values:</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        </dd>
    </dlentry>
</dl>
</refbody>
```

I think I need to use keys to do this, but I just can't get it to work properly. I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:key name="kValues" match="p" 
    use="generate-id[preceding::li[1]]"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ul[ancestor::refbody][1]">
    <dl>
        <xsl:for-each select="child::li|following::li">
            <xsl:variable name="vValues">
                <xsl:value-of select="key('kValues',generate-id())"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <dlentry>
                <dt>
                    <xsl:value-of select="child::uicontrol"/>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                     <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                    <xsl:if test="$vValues">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$vValues" />
                    </xsl:if>
                </dd>
            </dlentry>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </dl>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I. This transformation** (my solution using keys):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:key name="kFollowing"
      match="node()[self::p or self::text() and preceding-sibling::ul]"
      use="generate-id(preceding::li[1])"/>

     <xsl:template match="/*[ul]">
         <refbody>
             <dl>
               <xsl:apply-templates/>
             </dl>
         </refbody>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="li">
         <dlentry>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </dlentry>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="li/text()">
         <dd>
           <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
         </dd>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="li[last()]/text()">
         <dd>
           <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           <xsl:copy-of select="key('kFollowing', generate-id(..))"/>
         </dd>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="uicontrol">
         <dt>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </dt>
     </xsl:template>
     <xsl:template match="p/text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<refbody>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <uicontrol>FOO</uicontrol>BAR
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p>Values: 000 - 999</p>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <uicontrol>FOO</uicontrol>BAR
        </li>
        <li>
            <uicontrol>FOO</uicontrol>BAR
        </li>
        <li>
            <uicontrol>FOO</uicontrol>BAR
        </li>
        <li>
            <uicontrol>FOO</uicontrol>BAR
        </li>
    </ul>
    <p>Values:</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    <p>lorem ipsum</p>
</refbody>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<refbody>
   <dl>
      <dlentry>
         <dt>FOO</dt>
         <dd>BAR
        <p>Values: 000 - 999</p>
         </dd>
      </dlentry>
      <dlentry>
         <dt>FOO</dt>
         <dd>BAR</dd>
      </dlentry>
      <dlentry>
         <dt>FOO</dt>
         <dd>BAR</dd>
      </dlentry>
      <dlentry>
         <dt>FOO</dt>
         <dd>BAR</dd>
      </dlentry>
      <dlentry>
         <dt>FOO</dt>
         <dd>BAR
        <p>Values:</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
            <p>lorem ipsum</p>
         </dd>
      </dlentry>
   </dl>
</refbody>
```

---

**II. Your solution after correcting all found mistakes:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 
    <xsl:key name="kValues" match="p"
        use="generate-id(preceding::li[1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul[ancestor::refbody][1]">
        <dl>
            <xsl:for-each select="child::li|following::li">
                <xsl:variable name="vValues" select="key('kValues',generate-id())"/>
                <dlentry>
                    <dt>
                        <xsl:value-of select="child::uicontrol"/>
                    </dt>
                    <dd>
                         <xsl:value-of select="text()[normalize-space()]"/>
                         <xsl:copy-of select="$vValues" />
                    </dd>
                </dlentry>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </dl>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="p|ul|text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this corrected transformation is applied on the same XML document (above) it produces exactly the wanted, correct result**.

---

**III. Analysis of the mistakes that I found**:

1. This is an error that requires good eyes to see:

...

```
<xsl:key name="kValues" match="p"             
         use="generate-id[preceding::li[1]]"/>
```

...

here any `p` element is indexed by the string value of its `generate-id` children that have a preceding `li`.

However, there are no elements named `generate-id` in the XML document.

**What was really intended was to use the `generate-id()` function**. Function calls are formed by the name of the function, followed by a sequence of its actual argument values, enclosed in regular, round brackets `(` and `)`. Replacing the round brackets by square brackets radically changes the semantics of the expression, turning the function call into a (relative) location step.

.2. **This**:

```
        <xsl:variable name="vValues">                               
          <xsl:value-of select="key('kValues',generate-id())"/>                           
        </xsl:variable>
```

**Is not only a (very) bad practice, but is often cause of errors**, like in the current case. You are creating a tree (document node), not a nodeset of elements. The tree always has at least one node (the document node) and its boolean value, therefore is always true.

Never ever use the above syntax.

**The correct variable declaration is**:

```
            <xsl:variable name="vValues" select="key('kValues',generate-id())"/>
```

.3. There are no template rules to prevent the copying by the identity template of any unwanted `ul`, `p`, and `text()` nodes and these appear in the result of the original transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Dimitre. The result is not quite correct, as it produces two `<dl>`. The intent is to combine all `<ul>` in the document into a single `<dl>`.

Comment: @ChadDybdahl: It seems I misunderstood the question -- will have a look later today.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the transformation included in the question does consolidate all `<ul>` into a single `<dl>`. I think there's just something wrong with my use of keys. I would be extremely grateful if you could tell me what's wrong with my stylesheet, because it looks to me like it should be working (although it doesn't, so the defect is obviously in me, not in XSLT).

Comment: @ChadDybdahl: I have updated the answer so that the transformation now produces the wanted result.

Comment: @ChadDybdahl: I have also added as Part II. ypur solution after I corrected all found mistakes in it -- it now works as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much, not only for the solution, but for taking the time to find the errors in my code. My transformation, as corrected, does indeed produce the correct result (as does yours, of course). Thank you!

Comment: @ChadDybdahl: You are welcome -- SO is a learning experience for us all.

Answer (score 1):

The following stylesheet produces the desired output without the use of keys.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="refbody">
        <xsl:copy>
            <dl>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="ul" />
            </dl>
        </xsl:copy>        
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ul">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li">
        <dlentry><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></dlentry>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="uicontrol">
        <dt><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></dt>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="li/text()">
        <dd>
            <xsl:copy/>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                 select="parent::li
                                 [not(following-sibling::li)]
                                 /parent::ul
                                 /following-sibling::p
                                 [
                                  count(preceding-sibling::ul) 
                                  = count(current()/../../preceding-sibling::ul)
                                    +1
                                 ]"/>
        </dd>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```